# CoreLocation "significant location changes" vs. "region monitoring"

Tags: ios, core-location, geofencing

Goal:

I want an app that will give the user a location notification when they are near a location of interest.  (For instance, "you are within 100ft of XYZ")

The Core Location documentation stresses that the low-battery-impact way of monitoring location is with `-[CLLocationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges]`.  This does not appear to require the app to run with `UIBackgroundModes`.

Does the same thing apply for region monitoring?  I want to use `[CLLocationManager startMonitoringForRegion:]` -- I can't tell from the documentation whether the app has to run in the background to receive geofencing updates.  I want to have as little drain on the user's battery as possible.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`startMonitoringForRegion` is exactly what you want. The app doesn't need to be running in the background, it will be woken to handle any updates from the OS.